# Algebra 1: Setting Up a problem and solving

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When Gina worked $10$ hours overtime,  she earned $\$8$ more than one-third the amount she normally earns for $40$ hours of work at her usual rate.

If her overrate time is $\$2.40$ per hour more than her usual rate, find her overtime rate.

How would you go about setting up and solving a problem as such?

Answer (score 3):

Let's note $x$ the hour wage of Gina and $y$ her overtime wage.

With this we can translate the sentences you gave into equations :

*When Gina worked 10 hours overtime, she earned $8 more than one-third the amount she normally earns for 40 hours of work at her usual rate.*

This translate to : $$10y = 8 + {1\over 3}\cdot 40x$$

*her overrate time is $2.40$ per hour more than her usual rate*

This translate to :

$$y = x+2.40$$

Now we got a system of two equations with two variables $x,y$

$$\left\{ \begin{align}
-{1\over 3}\cdot 40x& +10y &= 8  \\
-x &+ y& = 2.40 \end{align}\right.$$

Can you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to solve without using a system of two equations, as my students have not learned systems yet. But it seems that because there are two variables, this is really the only way. Thank you!

Comment: @plonialmoni Not a problem, keep in mind, for this kind of problems, translating the statements into equations is arguably the hard part, but if you practice one or two more you'll get the hang of it.
Feel free to post your answer once you solve the system of equations =)

Comment: I though you were a student, pardon me. Maybe there is other ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is her usual rate, then $r+2.40$ is her overtime rate.  So 
for $10$ hours overtime she earns $10 \times (r+2.40)$.  For $40$ hours
regular time she earns $40 \times r$.  Then $8$ more than a third of that is
$8+\frac{40r}{3}.$  So the equation is

$$10(r+2.40) = 8 +\frac{40r}{3}.$$